# Idea behind Grothendieck's proof that formally smooth implies flat?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, ac.commutative-algebra, schemes, flatness

From [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/15200/69037) I learned that Grothendieck proved the following result.

**Theorem.** Every formally smooth morphism between locally noetherian schemes is flat.

The book *Smoothness, Regularity, and Complete Intersection* by Majadas and Rodicio cites the following result.

**Theorem.** Let $(A,\mathfrak m,K)\to (B,\mathfrak n, L)$ be a local homomorphism of noetherian local rings. Then TFAE.

- $B$ is a formally smooth $A$ algebra for the $\mathfrak n$-adic topology;
- $B$ is a flat $A$-module and the $K$ algebra $B\otimes_AK$ is geometrically regular.

The authors then write:

> This result is due to Grothendieck [EGA 0$_{\rm{IV}}$ , (19.7.1)]. His proof is
>   long, though it provides a lot of additional information. He uses this
>   result in proving Cohen’s theorems on the structure of complete noetherian local rings. An alternative proof of (I) was given by M. André [An1],
>   based on André –Quillen homology theory; it thus uses simplicial methods, that are not necessarily familiar to all commutative algebraists. A
>   third proof was given by N. Radu [Ra2], making use of Cohen’s theorems
>   on complete noetherian local rings.

**Questions:**

1. Are there any English references for the proof of Grothendieck or of André?
2. What is the *conceptual* outline of Grothendieck's proof?

André's *Homologie des Algèbres Commutatives* does not look very geometric to a novice like me and I was hoping perhaps Grothendieck's path was more geometric. I would also like to at least glimpse the big picture of the proof.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by geometric. Flatness (used effectively by Grothendieck and forms the backbone in many ways) is a purely algebraic concept.

Answer (score 5):

You have a very short proof by Jesús Conde in the paper

A short proof of smooth implies flat.
*Comm. Algebra* **45** (2017), no. 2, 774–775.

https://doi.org/10.1080/00927872.2016.1175461

see, alternatively, https://arxiv.org/abs/1504.05709

Comment: The introductory paragraph to this paper mentions the result by Grothendieck and seems to prove a weaker statement.

Answer (score 3):

In Matsumura's *Commutatuve Ring Theory*, you will find the following weaker version of Grothendieck result (Theorem $28.10$):

Let $(A, \mathfrak{m},k)$ be a local ring and $B$ a flat $A$-algebra. Suppose that $B_0 = B \otimes_{A} k$ is $0$-smooth over $k$. Then $B$ is $\mathfrak{m}B$-smooth over $A$.

Matsumura proves it with basic commutative algebra. On the other hand, the geometric **translation** of Grothendieck's result seems to be rather clear:

let $f : X \longrightarrow Y$ be a morphism of schemes of finite type over a base field $k$. Let $x \in X$. Then $f$ is locally smooth around $x$ if and only if $f$ is locally flat around $x$ and the fiber $f^{-1}(f(x))$ is smooth at $x$ over $k$.

This is proved in Hartschorne as Theorem 10.2, with only elementary methods from commutative algebra. On the other hand I am slightly cheating by saying that the condition:

> $B$ is formally smooth $A$-algebra for the $\mathfrak{n}$-adic topology

is translated geometrically into:

> $f$ is locally smooth at $x$

But from a geometer's point of view, it's really what it looks like (at least on a formal neighborhood).