# Formally smooth with smooth fibers but not smooth

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Is there a simple example of a morphism of schemes $X\rightarrow S$ that is

- [formally smooth](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02GZ)
- for any point $p\in S$, the base change $X\times_S\mathrm{Spec}\:k(p)\rightarrow \mathrm{Spec}\:k(p)$ is a [smooth](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01V4) morphism
- [flat](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01U3)
- not [locally of finite presentation](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01TP)?

Comment: How about the map $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbf{Q}) \to \mathrm{Spec}(\mathbf{Z})$?

Comment: @Boa  That is not formally smooth.  Let $P\subset \mathbb{Z}_{>0}$ be the set of prime integers.  Let $C$ be the commutative ring $\mathbb{Z}[x_p : p\in P]$.  Then $\mathbb{Q}$ is the quotient algebra $C/J$ for the ideal $J=\langle px_p - 1 : p\in P \rangle$.  Now consider the algebra $B=\mathbb{Z}_2[x_2]/\langle 4x_2^2-4x_2 + 1 \rangle$  The quotient by the square-zero ideal $\langle 2x_2 -1\rangle$ equals $\mathbb{Z}_2[x_2]/\langle 2x_2-1\rangle = \mathbb{Q}_2$. This contains $\mathbb{Q}$.  There is no $2$-divisible element in $B$ that maps to $1/2$ in $\mathbb{Q}_2$.

Comment: I was wrong.  The element $2x_2(1-x_2)$ is $2$-divisible and maps to $x_2$.

Comment: Yes, I think the argument is okay (that is why I upvoted).

Answer (score 2):

Consider the map suggested by Boa. For any integral domain $R$, the fraction field with its usual $R$-module structure [is](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1259488/680178) flat. So the second bullet point is satisfied (alternatively, the second bullet point follows from the first because formally smooth morphisms between locally Noetherian schemes [are](https://mathoverflow.net/a/15200/141498) flat).

For any point $p\in\mathrm{Spec}\:\mathbb{Z}$, the base change of the morphism $\mathrm{Spec}\: \mathbb{Q}\rightarrow \mathrm{Spec}\:\mathbb{Z}$ is either the unique morphism from the empty scheme so vacuously smooth (this is the case iff $p$ is a closed point) or it is an isomorphism (this is the case iff $p$ is the generic point). So the third bullet point is satisfied.

The set-theoretic image of the morphism $\mathrm{Spec}\:\mathbb{Q}\rightarrow \mathrm{Spec}\:\mathbb{Z}$ is not open so it [can not](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01UA) be locally of finite presentation. So the fourth bullet point is satisfied.

Let $P$ be the set of positive prime numbers, think of $\mathbb{Q}$ as a $\mathbb{Z}$-algebra on generators indexed by $P$ and with the relations $px_p=1$ for all $p \in P$. Let $B$ be a commutative unital ring with a square-zero ideal $I$. Assume we have a morphism $\psi:\mathbb{Q}\rightarrow B/I$. Since the map $\pi:B\rightarrow B/I$ is surjective, for any prime $p$ we can find an element $a$ in the inverse image of $\psi(x_p)$ such that $pa=1+i$ for some $i\in I$. Set $a'=a(1-i)$. $a'$ belongs to the inverse image of $\psi(x_p)$ and satisfies $pa'=pa(1-i)=(1+i)(1-i)=1$.

Once the map is defined on the generators, it extends to monomials by multiplicativity and to the whole algebra by additivity, so we have a homomorphism $\phi:\mathbb{Q}\rightarrow B$ that satisfies $\pi\circ\phi=\psi$.

Therefore, $\phi$ solves the lifting problem, i.e. the map $\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{Q}$ is formally smooth. So the first bullet point is satisfied.